# RxJava fromCallable and unsubscription

Tags: java, rx-java

I have the following code (RxJava 1.3.8):

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

Subscription subscription1 = Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.println("first Callable executed");
  return 0;
})
    .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    .subscribe();

Subscription subscription2 = Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.println("second Callable executed");
  return 0;
})
    .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    .subscribe();

CompositeSubscription subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
subscriptions.addAll(subscription1, subscription2);
subscriptions.clear();
```

Output:

> first Callable executed
>
> second Callable executed

The question is - why was second Callable executed? Before it runs I expect that subscription checked and execution canceled if subscription is unsubscribed.

Comment: Works for me; nothing is printed if I run your code, even if looped.

Comment: @akarnokd actually I run this code in Android environment (MainActivity::onCreate), messages printed with Log::d, RxJava version - 1.3.5. Maybe it matters

Comment: Try with 1.3.8, the latest version of the now unsupported 1.x line.

Comment: @akarnokd 1.3.8 - same behavior, but on 2.2.1 - nothing is printed. Is it a bug or 1x intended behavior?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with 1.3.8 so I can't say for sure. Besides, 1.x is end of life so there is no point in spending to much time over this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription is only checked before it emits a value but it would appear that it will trigger the callable regardless.

```
public static Completable fromCallable(final Callable<?> callable) {
    requireNonNull(callable);
    return create(new OnSubscribe() {
        @Override
        public void call(rx.CompletableSubscriber s) {
            BooleanSubscription bs = new BooleanSubscription();
            s.onSubscribe(bs);
            try {
                // calls the callable regardless
                callable.call();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                if (!bs.isUnsubscribed()) {
                    s.onError(e);
                }
                return;
            }
            // the emission of the complete is guarded
            if (!bs.isUnsubscribed()) {
                s.onCompleted();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So if we were to modify your code as follows adding a `doOnComplete` to each.

```
Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

Subscription subscription1 = Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.println("first Callable executed");
  return 0;
})
    .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("first Completable complete"))
    .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    .subscribe();

Subscription subscription2 = Completable.fromCallable(() -> {
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.println("second Callable executed");
  return 0;
})
    .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println("second Completable complete"))
    .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    .subscribe();

CompositeSubscription subscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
subscriptions.addAll(subscription1, subscription2);
subscriptions.clear();
```

We get:

```
first Callable executed
second Callable executed
```

If we do not clear the subscriptions we will see the extra output, i.e.

```
first Callable executed
first Completable complete
second Callable executed
second Completable complete
```